# Bluetooth pairing - how to show the simple Cancel/Pair dialog?

Tags: android, android-intent, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-oob

I have prepared [a simple test project](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/tree/q29/QR_BT_Pairing) for this question at GitHub.

I am trying to create an Android app, which would scan a QR code from a computer screen and then use the data (MAC address and PIN or hash) for *easy* pairing (bonding) with a Bluetooth device.

Similar to the popular [InstaWifi app](http://www.instawifi.jessechen.net/) - but for Classic Bluetooth.

For testing purposes I don't do any barcode scanning yet, but just display a list of devices:

[image: list of devices]

After user touches one of the devices, pairing is tried in [MainActivity.java](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/q29/QR_BT_Pairing/src/de/afarber/qr_bt_pairing/MainActivity.java):

```
private void startBluetoothPairing(BluetoothDevice device) {
    Intent pairingIntent = new Intent(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST);
    pairingIntent.putExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE, device);
    pairingIntent.putExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_PAIRING_VARIANT,
                BluetoothDevice.PAIRING_VARIANT_PIN);
    pairingIntent.putExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_PAIRING_KEY, 1234);
    //device.setPin(new byte[]{1,2,3,4});  <- DOES NOT CHANGE ANYTHING
    //device.setPairingConfirmation(false);
    startActivityForResult(pairingIntent, REQUEST_BT_SETTINGS);
}
```

Unfortunately, the popup still asks for PIN:

[image: pin dialog]

Because I have actually specified a PIN in my source code, I was actually expecting another, simpler system dialog to be shown (this one is shown when doing NFC OOB pairing):

[image: pair dialog]

From searching for solutions, I know that there is a [setPin()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html) method, but it is not applicable here (or is it?) - because I am trying to pair the whole smartphone to the Bluetooth device and not just the app...

**My question:** How to make Android OS to show the simple Cancel/Pair dialog?

Searching for [Bluetooth pairing request](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/search?l=html&q=Bluetooth%20pairing%20request) string at GitHub has not shown any hints...

**UPDATE:** On unrealsoul007's suggestion (thanks) I have update the source code in [MainActivity.java](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/q30/QR_BT_Pairing/src/de/afarber/qr_bt_pairing/MainActivity.java) and now the simple Cancel/Pair dialog is displayed:

```
private void startBluetoothPairing(BluetoothDevice device) {
    Intent pairingIntent = new Intent(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST);
    pairingIntent.putExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE, device);
    pairingIntent.putExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_PAIRING_VARIANT,
        BluetoothDevice.PAIRING_VARIANT_PASSKEY_CONFIRMATION);
    pairingIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivityForResult(pairingIntent, REQUEST_BT_PAIRING);
}
```

However I am not sure how to complete the pairing process - because `onActivityResult` is called with `resultCode=0` even before the dialog is closed:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    // this is called before user clicks Cancel or Pair in the dialog
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_BT_PAIRING) { 
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {  // 0 != -1
            Log.d("XXX", "Let#s pair!!!!"); // NOT CALLED
        }

        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: does `onActivityResult` get called after clicking Pair as well..?

Comment: Does the onActivityResult called after picking pair or just when the popup is up?

Comment: have you managed to make it happen only when you accepted the pairing?

Comment: Nope, I've ended up using createBond()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are being prompted for entering the pin because that is what you are requesting in your `pairingIntent`.

Instead of using

```
pairingIntent.putExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_PAIRING_VARIANT,
                BluetoothDevice.PAIRING_VARIANT_PIN);
pairingIntent.putExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_PAIRING_KEY, 1234);
```

Use

```
pairingIntent.putExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_PAIRING_VARIANT, PAIRING_VARIANT_PASSKEY_CONFIRMATION);
```

As mentioned [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#PAIRING_VARIANT_PASSKEY_CONFIRMATION),

> The user will be prompted to confirm the passkey displayed on the
>   screen or an app will confirm the passkey for the user.

Comment: Thank you (+1) now the simple Cancel/Pair dialog is displayed. I wonder what to do next to complete the pairing - should I implement `onReceive` method for some broadcasted event?

Comment: since you are starting Activity for Result, you will get the result of it in `onActivityResult`.

Comment: Also you can play with various intents mentioned here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html

Comment: Unfortunately, `onActivityResult` is called even before user touches Cancel or Pair button in the dialog - please see my updated question.

Comment: @unrealsoul007 I need it to happen when the user accept the pairing dialog, do you know something about it?